# A template question: Can compiler deduce template type in static method

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following setup:

A templated class SpecialModel:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class SpecialModel<A, B> {
};
```

A templated Worker, working on some kind of Model:

```
template<typename M>
class Worker<M> {

    Worker(M& model);

    void work();
 };
```

And a specialization of Worker for SpecialModel:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Worker<SpecialModel<A, B> > {

    Worker(SpecialModel& model);

    void work();
};
```

Finally, there is a class that handels
a given worker through a static method,
basically this Manager class does lots of
administration things to allow Worker
focus on the real work:

```
template<typename W>
class Manager<W> {

    Manager() {};

    static void getThingsDone(W worker) {
        ...;
        worker.work();
        ...;
    };
};
```

To 'getThingsDone' for a SpecialModel, I need the following
in the code:

```
SpecialModel<A1, B1> spmo;
Worker< SpecialModel<A1, B1> > w(spmo);
Manager<Worker< SpecialModel<A1, B1> > >::getThingsDone(w);
```

The last line is the one I have problems with. Isn't
there a way to just say:

```
Manager::getThingsDone(w);
```

Can't the compiler deduce the type of W from w?

Why do i want that, anyway? I have an array of Workers,
working on different kinds of SpecialModels (different As and
Bs). Now i want to loop over this array, calling Manager::getThingsDone(w) on
each worker. How should i be able to pass typeinformation
on to Manager, when only having the array of workers?
(The array of SpecialModles is known at compile time (part
of this code is autogenerated and then compiled for this
kind of special input), the array will be defined somewhere 
at the toplevel of the code, yet, the code doing the work 
should be as general as possible. However, i would be happy to
find an answer without regard to this last point).

Comment: Um, where did that `Train` thing enter, and why did you introduce the `Manager` go?

Comment: Your question is very long although you really only want to ask why the compiler is unable to deduce a template argument. See my answer below.

Comment: Uhhhm, *blush*, fixed it (damn copy&paste).

Comment: Sebastian, you are right. But i wasn't sure if everything boils down to this, that's why i was detailed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Train is a templated class, as it appears to be, the compiler cannot deduce **class** templates from static **method** template arguments.

If Train::train is a static method, why is your class Train templated? Method train cannot access any member variables anyway. You could probably make train a free function:

```
template<class W>
void train(W const& w) { ... }
```

And in your code you could simply do

```
train(w);
```

If class Train must be templated with type Worker, you could write a helper function that can discover the template parameter automatically:

```
template<class W>
Train<W> make_trainer(W const& w) { return Train<W>(w); }
```

You can also make train a static function of class Train with its own template parameter:

```
class Train {
   template<class W>
   vod train(W const& w) { ... }
};
```

Your code could then call

```
Train::train(w);
```

What's best depends on your exact use case.